# Qt Webview Google Maps Caching

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, caching, qwebview

I've created a Google maps widget that sub-classes QWebView. Basically, all of the google maps stuff is written in Javascript (using Google's Javascript API) and saved in an html file stored locally. Then, the widget just displays the html....and does some other stuff, but that's irrelevant.

The issue I am having is that the map tiles take significantly longer to load than if I open up the same html file in, say Chrome or Safari. Aren't Chrome and Safari based on the same WebKit that Qt uses?

Has anyone run into a similar situation? Is there a way to cache the map tiles so that it doesn't have to re-fetch them every time the display gets updated? Ideally, I would like to be able to cache them permanently so that my program can run off-line, but I know that is against Google's TOS. I will settle for being able to cache the tiles to speed up panning/zooming.

In searching around various forums, using QNetworkDiskCache has come up as a potential solution, but no one seems to be able to get that to work. I just can't seem to figure out why the same html/javascript runs significantly faster in Chrome and Safari than in QWebView

Comment: Have you checked out `QWebSetttings` class? There are some settings which may speed up browsing and interaction. Like `QWebSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled`, `QWebSettings::OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled` and `QWebSettings::TiledBackingStoreEnabled`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Ammar. I tried adding those settings using "this->settings()->setAttribute(...)" along with a call to setOfflineWebApplicationCachePath(...), but that didn't seem to help at all. At first, trying to enable TiledBackingStore, dramatically slowed down the application. I then converted the QWebView to a QGraphicsWebView and tried again. This time, all that is displayed is a checker board pattern.

Comment: Your best bet is to watch the network traffic and see what resources are being pulled. Also "same WebKit" does not exist, see my explanation here http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/06/your-webkit-port-is-special-just-like-every-other-port.html.

Comment: @AriyaHidayat thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "watch the network traffic and see what resources are being pulled"?

Comment: Try to debug the network traffic. It can be done via a proxy or inject your own modified network access manager, see http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2010/05/qnetworkaccessmanager-tracenet-speed-tracer.html for my example.

Answer (score 0):

QNetworkDiskCache works fine with a Google map, with significant speed improvements compared to when it is not enabled. This should do the trick:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkDiskCache *diskCache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);

diskCache->setCacheDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/cache");
manager->setCache(diskCache);
```

You then add the manager to your webView:

```
frame->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(manager);
frame->page()->settings()->setMaximumPagesInCache(10);
```

Then go on and load your html

```
frame->setHtml(...);
```